# Inserting an Array of Characters into DB

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to insert a 2 dimensional array into a DB table. Is there any way to insert these values into DB with a single INSERT statement rather than using multiple INSERT statements? These multiple statements create a tendency for DB connection pool issues and can create a latency in the application.

```
String[][] a = new String[10][2];
for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
{
        st.executeUpdate("Insert into sap_details  VALUES a[i][0],a[i][1]);
}
```

What happens here is there are effectively 10 INSERT statements being called for each row. I don't want it to; it should happen with only one INSERT statement.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use JDBC [Batch Updates](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec2/jdbc2.1.frame6.html)? Using prepared statements should also help.

#### Example

```
    String[][] a = new String[10][2];
    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO sap_details VALUES (?,?)");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pst.setString(1, a[i][0]);
        pst.setString(2, a[i][1]);
        pst.addBatch();
    }
    int[] results = pst.executeBatch();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I think that should help me get away with any issues that may arise out of Connection pool issues / Deadlock or any DB issues arising out if multiple INSERT statements.

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL, something like this should do the trick, perfectly fine , Oracle won't like it.  This feature is supported by DB2, SQL Server (since version 10.0 - i.e. 2008), PostgreSQL (since version 8.2), MySQL, and H2.

```
        String[][] a = new String[10][2];    
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Insert into sap_details (a,b) VALUES ");               
        for(int i =0;i<a.length;i++){
                sb.append("(\'");
                sb.append(a[i][0]);
                sb.append("\',\'");
                sb.append(a[i][1]);
                sb.append("\')");
                if(i < a.length -1 )
                    sb.append(",");
         }
         st.executeUpdate(sb.toString());
```

Comment: It really is best to avoid hand-rolled SQL strings, if at all possible.

Comment: With User Input you can't control, I definitely would go with prepared statements. But I kind of like this style.

Comment: Thanks, but i am using Oracle DB.